# Error while running sudo apt-get update: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'"

Tags: apt, 18.04, package-management, sudo

I am relatively new to Ubuntu. I have been trying to run `sudo apt-get update` only to get a error. This has not happened to me before.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease             
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release               
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:5 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease             
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease     
Hit:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                    
Hit:8 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease            
Hit:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease          
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]  
Fetched 88.7 kB in 9s (9,888 B/s)                    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 8, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.creator import DbCreator
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 11, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 8, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.creator import DbCreator
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 11, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

What could be causing this problem, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy  and paste the text. Format it by `{}` icon.

Answer (score 0):

So i solved the error.
I uninstalled python and installed it again and boom!